# mysql db backup excluding specific tables

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5, mysqldump

Are there any mysql scripts for taking a database backup by excluding specified tables?

Also, what is the best way to take backup of a running mysql system?

Comment: What OS? Community or Enterprise? InnoDB or MyISAM or ... ?

Comment: If you are not sure, connect to MySQL, type use information_schema; and then type: select table_schema, table_name, engine from tables where table_schema='database_name';

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do to mysqldump specific table(s)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-to-mysqldump-specific-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can backup databases and tables using the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command.  There are parameters for excluding certain tables.

```
mysqldump -u username -ppasswword -h servername --ignore-table=dbname.tabletoskip dbname
```

If you need to get fast backups of MyISAM or ARCHIVE tables, you can also use [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html).  That has more restrictions though.

Comment: This is as StraightForward an answer as possible. +1 !!!

Comment: Yeah,  it is best to start with the simple solutions, and only work up to the complex home-brew scripts when you know you need it.

Comment: Thanks Cylindric..It worked for me for excluding one table..How to exclude more than one table

Comment: Can we use this method for backing up a running DB

Comment: Like it says on the page I linked, "To ignore multiple tables, use this option multiple times."