# How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

How can I dump a specific table or set of tables without including the rest of the db tables?

Comment: See also: [Any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35081/1192)

Comment: mysqldump --defaults-group-suffix=db your_db table_name | gzip > table_name-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).sql.gz

Answer (score 735, accepted):

If you are dumping tables `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` from `mydb`

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3 > mydb_tables.sql
```

If you have a ton of tables in `mydb`  and you want to dump everything except `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`, do this:

```
DBTODUMP=mydb
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 10240;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name separator ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${DBTODUMP}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name NOT IN ('t1','t2','t3')"
TBLIST=`mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"${SQL}"`
mysqldump -u... -p... ${DBTODUMP} ${TBLIST} > mydb_tables.sql
```

## UPDATE 2014-03-06 10:15 EST

[@RoryDonohue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/35251/rory-donohue) pointed out to me that the [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function needs to have its max length extended. I added the session variable [**group_concat_max_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to my answer with a length max of 10K.

Comment: To exclude just a few tables you can use  --ignore-table=Table1  --ignore-table=Table2  --ignore-table=Table3 etc.

Comment: @codecowboy, you can change `SQL="${SQL} AND table_name NOT IN ('t1','t2','t3')"` to `SQL="${SQL} AND table_name NOT LIKE 'foo\_%'"`. I  just tested it and it works. You could change the condition to '%foo%' to get all tables containing 'foo' anywhere in their names (including 'food', 'fool', etc).

Comment: Isn't the approach for *excluding* tables here redundant and overkill given the existence of the `--ignore-table` argument? And if so, wouldn't it be better to scrap your script from the answer and just recommend `--ignore-table` instead?

Comment: @codewaggle That gives the error `Illegal use of option --ignore-table=<database>.<table>` unless I specify the table as `schemaname.tablename`.

Comment: cool stuff, any reason SQL variable is not multi-line?

Comment: It s just not working `Access denied for user to database t1 when selecting database`

Comment: How do I apply multiple tables `t1`, `t2`, `t3` using the option `--tables` ?

Comment: You can pipe the output to zip command to compress the dump:
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3 | zip mydb_tables.sql.zip

Answer (score 92):

A note to expand on [the answer by RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9309/1192).

The script he included is a great approach for including (`and table_name in`) or excluding (`and table_name NOT in`) a list of tables.

If you just need to exclude one or two tables, you can exclude them individually with the `--ignore-table` option:

```
mysqldump -u -p etc. --ignore-table=Database.Table1 --ignore-table=Database.Table2 > dump_file.sql
```

Answer (score 37):

When you have more than a few tables it is much better running something like this:

```
mysql databasename -u [user] -p[password] -e 'show tables like "table_name_%"' 
       | grep -v Tables_in 
       | xargs mysqldump [databasename] -u [root] -p [password] > [target_file]
```

Or somethink like this:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[password] databasename `echo "show tables like 'table_name_%';" 
       | mysql -u[user] -p[password] databasename 
       | sed '/Tables_in/d'` > [target_file]
```

Remember that those commands must be typed in one line only.

Comment: Why is the `'/Tables_in/d'` needed resp. how does it work? For `sed` (stream editor) I found https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/ and for `$d` this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39600392/1066234 with "delete line"?

Answer (score 18):

You can do it simply using below command:

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword dbname \
  --ignore-table=schema.tablename1    \
  --ignore-table=schema.tablename2    \
  --ignore-table=schema.tablename3 > mysqldump.sql
```

Comment: --ignore-table is to exclude certain tables from mysqldump, not to include . :)

Comment: Yet one could list all the tables to exclude and it would dump just the ones remaining :-)