# Any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

We have 40 databases in our server.

We want to take 36 databases backup using mysqldump. How can i ignore remaining 4 databases in mysqldump command? Is there any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup in MySQL?

I know the general mysqldump command but it is very lengthy. I want to ignore only 4 databases and need to take remaining dbs backup.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Back on Dec 16, 2011, I answered the question [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables/9309#9309)

I collected all tables not including a certain set of table names.

Using the same principles, you could have collect all the database names from the metadata table `information_schema.schemata` that you want mysqldump'd, create a query to return that list, then use that list of databases to formulate the mysqldump command.

```
DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="db1 db2 db3"
EXCLUSION_LIST="'information_schema','mysql'"
for DB in `echo "${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE}"`
do
    EXCLUSION_LIST="${EXCLUSION_LIST},'${DB}'"
done
SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN (${EXCLUSION_LIST})"
MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="--databases"
for DB in `mysql -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
do
    MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} ${DB}"
done
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers"
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} > MySQLDatabases.sql
```

All you need to do is put the databases you do not want mysqldump'd into `DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: There's no need to exclude `information_schema` it isn't being dumped anyways. 

`mysqldump does not dump the INFORMATION_SCHEMA or performance_schema database by default. To dump either of these, name it explicitly on the command line and also use the --skip-lock-tables option. You can also name them with the --databases option. Before MySQL 5.5 mysqldump silently ignores INFORMATION_SCHEMA even if you name it explicitly on the command line.`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: thanks for the `--routines --triggers`
an other one not to miss out is `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` or loose all emoticons

Answer (score 21):

Use grep to exclude databases you don't want:

```
candidates=$(echo "show databases" | mysql | grep -Ev "^(Database|mysql|performance_schema|information_schema)$")
mysqldump --databases $candidates
```

From looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit it seems like you'll be able to handle long lines. Otherwise you can always

```
candidates=$(echo "show databases" | mysql | grep -Ev "^(Database|mysql|performance_schema|information_schema)$")
for candidate in $candidates[*]; do
    mysqldump $candidate 
done
```

Comment: One should add ` | paste -sd " " -` after the `grep` in order to pass from multiline output to a single line with each database name seperated by a space, which is required by `mysqldump`. So the command will be `candidates=$(echo "show databases" | mysql | grep -Ev "^(Database|mysql|performance_schema|information_schema)$" | paste -sd " " -)`

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it is possible, but you can try these solution which you will have to type the names of all the databases you want to dump.

```
mysqldump -u root -password --databases db1 db2 db3 ... db36 > mydb_dump.sql
```

Let me know if the solution helps.

Comment: i know this command .but it is very lengthy .i want to ignore 4 databases and need to take remaining dbs backup.

Answer (score 9):

Since MySQL 5.7.8, you can use `mysqlpump` (which is NOT the same as `mysqldump`) as follows:

```
mysqlpump --user=user --password --exclude-databases=db1,db2,db3,db4 --result-file=partial_backup.sql
```

Just replace `db1,db2,db3,db4` with the four databases you want to exclude.

Source: [MySQL Server Blog](https://mysqlserverteam.com/introducing-mysqlpump/)

Comment: This worked perfectly, can't believe I didn't know about this tool.

Answer (score 6):

Even here so many excellent answers, so this post is just to add one more choice. By below 2 lines in script, you can take your servers all DB's backup ignoring some DB.

```
DB_LIST=`mysql -Nse "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME SEPARATOR ' ') FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema','sys');"`

mysqldump -R -B $DB_LIST > BACKUPNAME.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for including `sys` since that is part of MySQL 5.7

Comment: thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, I always gets help from your excellent posts/blogs...thanks again for your compliment...

Comment: Thumbs up for the brevity of this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can look at the following links;

[Mysqldump Ignore Database Option](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/i-want-a-mysqldump-ignore-database-option-2012-04-18/)

```
            OR
```

[A few hacks to simulate mysqldump --ignore-database](http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2012/04/few-hacks-to-simulate-mysqldump-ignore.html)

[Implementing mysqldump –ignore-database](http://www.markleith.co.uk/2012/04/20/implementing-mysqldump-ignore-database/)

Let me know if the solution helps.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Many have always wanted mysqldump to ignore databases.

Would you believe that option exists now ??? No, not in mysqldump.

Oracle (Yuck, toowee, still doesn't roll off the tongue) has [DataPump (expdb impdp)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624) to dump Oracle databases. Since MySQL 5.7 in the Oracle family (still hurting), the new backup utility program is called [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html), which comes with [--exclude-databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_exclude-databases) and other neat options. Like its older stepbrother [datapump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624), [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html) also features [parallelism to help speed up dumps and divide work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#mysqlpump-parallelism). At this time, I have not incorporated into at the job, but it looks very promising. When I deep dive into [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html) I might find that it brings the same look and feel as Oracle's [datapump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624).

If there is anyone in the MySQL Parallel Universe with stories about it, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Rolando's answer is pretty great, but I wanted a script that can be reused across projects. So, I took his script and modified it so that you can do things like:

```
$ mysqldump-ignore-databases.sh 'myuser' 'mypwd' 'information_schema mysql performance_schema' '--skip-lock-tables' > mydbs.sql
```

Here is the modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is an adapted version of Rolando's awesome script at
# https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35104/94046

# Usage: mysqldump-ignore-databases.sh username password dbs-to-exclude mysqldump-options
# e.g.
#   mysqldumpIgnoreDatabases.sh 'myuser' 'mypwd' 'information_schema mysql performance_schema'
#                               '--skip-lock-tables' > dbs.sql
#
#   mysqldumpIgnoreDatabases.sh 'myuser' 'mypwd' 'mysql' '-h example.com' '-h example.com' > dbs.sql

USERNAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2
DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE=$3
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS=$4
MYSQL_OPTIONS=$5

EXCLUSION_LIST=""
for DB in `echo "${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE}"`
do
  if [ "${EXCLUSION_LIST}" != "" ]
  then
    EXCLUSION_LIST="${EXCLUSION_LIST},"
  fi
  EXCLUSION_LIST="${EXCLUSION_LIST}'${DB}'"
done

SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN (${EXCLUSION_LIST})"

MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="--databases"
for DB in `mysql -u${USERNAME} -p${PASSWORD} ${MYSQL_OPTIONS} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
do
  MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} ${DB}"
done

mysqldump -u${USERNAME} -p${PASSWORD} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES}
```

(I'm still hoping that an `--ignore-database` option will be added to a future version of mysqldump)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for production
It excludes `'performance_schema\|information_schema\|mysql\|sys'`...modify for your needs

```
MYSQL_USER=
MYSQL_PASS=
MYSQL_HOST=
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -h${MYSQL_HOST}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --single-transaction"

DBLIST=`mysql -s --host=$MYSQL_HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS \
--execute="SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -v \
'performance_schema\|information_schema\|mysql\|sys' | awk '{printf("\"%s\" ",$0)}'`

mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --databases ${DBLIST} | gzip >all-dbs.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to ignore certain database name using the below script.
I'm excluding information_schema database while running mysqldump. You may replace "information_schema" with database name you want to exclude.

```
for DB in $(mysql -u db_username -p'db_password' -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names); do
  if [ "$DB" != "information_schema" ]
  then
  mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables -u db_username -p'db_password' $DB | gzip > $DB.sql.gz;
  fi
done
```