# Get list of excluded databases from command line by asking user

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Based on [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35104/8227) I'm working on this bash script for export all databases from MySQL but exlude some ones and also system ones. This is how it looks like:

```
read -e -p "Enter MySQL root user: " -i "root" root_user
read -e -p "Enter MySQL root user password: " root_password

FILENAME="mysqlbck"-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T).sql
read -e -p "Enter backup filename: " -i "$FILENAME" file_name
read -e -p "Enter directory for save backup: " -i "/home" directory

DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE=""
EXCLUSION_LIST="'information_schema','performance_schema','mysql'"

for DB in `echo "${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE}"`
do
    EXCLUSION_LIST="${EXCLUSION_LIST},'${DB}'"
done

SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN (${EXCLUSION_LIST})"
MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="--databases"

for DB in `mysql -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
do
    MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} ${DB}"
done

MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers"
mysqldump -u"$root_user" -p ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} > "$directory/$filename"
```

I have two main issues around it:

- **DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE** should holds a comma separated list for each DB that I want to exclude, how do I ask, in command line, for those names and build something like db1,db2,db3 and so on and put the values on the var? I mean something like the flow below:

  ```
  Enter DB name: db1
  // DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="db1"
  Enter DB name: db2
  // DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="db1,db2"
  Enter DB name: db3
  // DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="db1,db2,db3"
  Enter DB name: 
  // got empty value stop asking for DB name 
  // and continue script execution on EXCLUSION_LIST line and below
  ```
- I'm having two issues executing the script as it's right now. See the console output below:

  ```
  Enter MySQL root user: root
  Enter MySQL root user password: ********
  Enter backup filename: mysqlbck-12-03-2015-11:49:22.sql
  Enter directory for save backup: /home
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  /usr/local/bin/script-task: line 132: /home/: Is a directory
  ```

  Why do I get access denied while trying to use `mysqldump`? I have tried the way you are seeing on the script above and also tried this one:

  ```
      mysqldump -u"$root_user" -p"$root_password" ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} > "$directory/$filename"
  ```

  Both have failed with same error, any advice?

  As per second issue shouldn't `$directory/$filename` read as `/home/mysqlbck-12-03-2015-11:49:22.sql` or the problem is the `%T` parameter and the `:` on the filename? Where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Please look back at [**my post**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/there-is-any-option-for-mysqldump-to-ignore-databases-for-backup-in-mysql/35104#35104) again.

- `DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE`

  - not supposed to be comma separated
  - supposed to be space separated
- `EXCLUSION_LIST`

  - supposed to be a comma-separated list of single-quote enclosed database names
  - this is for the sake of forming the SQL to extract names from `information_schema.schemata`

If you made `DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="db1,db2,db3"`, add the following lines to remove the commas

```
DBX=${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE}
DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE=`echo "${DBX}" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
```

Your filename should look at little different

```
FILENAME="mysqlbck"-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.sql
```

As for "Access Denied", you need to make sure you have the proper grants to the database.