# Mysql shutting down during a mysqldump of a specific database

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, crash

I have a server which is running Centos 6.6 with Cpanel.  I have been attempting to do mysqldump backups on individual databases.  All of the databases are under 5MB except for one.

The database that is around 250MB causes a mysql shutdown in the middle of running a mysqldump.  The other databases work fine during a mysqldump.

My question is could this be due to a corrupted database?  What should I do to start troubleshooting this?

Is there another way to backup this database other than mysqldump.  I just need one copy so I can move the troubled database to another server and remove it from this one.

Here is `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
table_open_cache=100K
max_connections=500
thread_cache_size=4
query_cache_size=8M
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_type=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
open_files_limit=10000
max_allowed_packet=268435456
innodb_buffer_pool_size=123731968
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: By default, mysqldump will dump databases in alphabetically order (character collation order for OS with case sensistivity). What is the name of the database that is corrupt ???

Comment: The name of the database is moments_production_wp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to mysqldump around `moments_production_wp`

I have old posts to bypass databases and tables

- `Dec 16, 2011` : [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables/9309#9309)
- `Feb 20, 2013` : [Any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/there-is-any-option-for-mysqldump-to-ignore-databases-for-backup-in-mysql/35104#35104)

Using the same concepts, here is how to mysqldump all except `moments_production_wp`

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE="moments_production_wp"
EXCLUSION_LIST="'information_schema','mysql','performance_schema'"
for DB in `echo "${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE}"`
do
    EXCLUSION_LIST="${EXCLUSION_LIST},'${DB}'"
done
SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN (${EXCLUSION_LIST})"
MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="--databases"
for DB in `mysql -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
do
    MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES="${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} ${DB}"
done
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --single-transaction"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${MYSQLDUMP_DATABASES} > GoodDatabases.sql
```

After dumping all the other databases, mysqldump the one database

```
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} moments_production_wp > OneDatabase.sql
```

It will mysqldump tables in alphabetical order. It should break near the bad table.

You can then mysqldump that database one table at a time

Let's say you know tables `tb1` and `tb2` makes mysqld crash

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
DBTODUMP=moments_production_wp
SQL="SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE table_schema='${DBTODUMP}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name NOT IN ('tb1','tb2')"
TBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN -e"${SQL}"`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --max-allowed-packet=1073741824"
for TB in `echo "${TBLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DBTODUMP} ${TB} > ${DBTODUMP}-${TB}.sql
done
```

This should help narrow the beam as to which table is causing the issue.

I do have one further thing to share. I have a 4-year-old post on the silent killer of mysqldumps : [MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323). You will need to set your [**`max_allowed_packet`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to `1G` in `my.cnf` and restart mysqld. If you cannot change the [**`max_allowed_packet`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) at this time, you should mysqldump one row at a time using `--skip-extended-insert` to throttle the amount of data passing into your [**current MySQL Packet**](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833).

Comment: Thanks Rolando,  I tried to dump just the trouble database and it brought the server and mysql down.  The first time it made it to 87MB for the dump.  The second the dump made it to 164MB which tells me the database might not be corrupted.

Comment: After restarting the mysql server could not be restarted and I ended up doing a force restart.  Mysql status said something about a lock file.  ` >root@moments [~]# service mysql restart
  ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
 Starting MySQL....... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/moments.serveroflight.com.pid).
 root@moments [~]# service mysql status
  ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists`

Comment: Is it crashing on the same table ?

Comment: You will have to `rm -f /var/lock/subsys/mysql`. Then, start mysql

Comment: I am sorry I wrote the wrong thing.  It is not crashing on the same table from what I can tell.

Comment: Is the entire database InnoDB or are there any MyISAM tables in the mix ???

Comment: Also, tell me, what is the name of the trouble table ???

Comment: I am sorry I wrote the wrong thing.  It is not crashing on the same table from what I can tell.  I accidentally wrote the wrong info.

Comment: It is a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM

Comment: Updated my answer ...

Comment: Ok, I was finally able to do a dump with this database.  It turns out the problem was the fact that the folder I was dumping to was an NFS server mounted folder. I changed the dump folder to a local folder rather than remote and it dumped correctly.  Thank you Rolando for helping me troubleshoot this.  I think the size of the database was causing the dump and the NFS server to not play friendly with each other.  Now I will need to find a different solution to NFS or troubleshoot it.  Thank You!!

Comment: I am marking your solution as correct as it would have solved my problem for what I was asking.

Comment: Nice work on the MySQL Packet answer, I will have to look into that.

Comment: The `max_allowed_packet=1G` setting worked for us with a very large MySQL table dump on Percona MySQL 5.6.29-76.2.  The earlier setting was 8M. Our kernel on this machine is 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 and the raw schema data size is around 750M.  

Interesting that every time this would 'go away' for us it actually causes a Kernel OOM killer event on the export thread which is recorded in `/var/log/messages`, the mysql_safe daemon restarts the DB afterwards.  Why would an OOM event be triggered with such a low `max_allowed_packet`?