# How would I exclude a group of tables based on a name prefix foo_* from a mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I'd like to exclude a group of tables from a mysqldump command (from a bash script). I might not know the exact table names ahead of time but they will be named with the prefix `foo_` or might contain another known suffix like `_BAK_[%Y%m%d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on answers from [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables)

To exclude all tables from a mysqldump that starts with `foo_`, here is the shell script to do it

```
MYSQL_DATA=mydb
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 102400;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('--ignore-table=',table_name) SEPARATOR ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${MYSQL_DATA}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name LIKE 'foo_%'"
EXCLUSION_LIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN -e"${SQL}"`
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQL_DATA} ${EXCLUSION_LIST} > ${MYSQL_DATA}_tables.sql
```

To exclude all tables from a mysqldump that starts with `foo_`, adjust this line

```
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name LIKE 'foo_%'"
```

to whatever pattern you need. Maybe you can use the [**REGEXP operator**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name REGEXP '\_BAK\_2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have the bash script show some kind of progress meter without affecting the output file?